# I can't find some icons in Flutter, such as Signal antenna

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm going to add an antenna icon in my project. Unfortunately, I didn't find any good icon. I've been searching for a hour, but there's nothing good enough.
The flutter has just an icon like this

> Icons.settings_input_antenna

that is not good and I don't like it.

Comment: why not add the fonts_awesome package?

Answer (score 1):

You can use use the font_awesome package to import additional icons

Add the following import to your yaml file

```
dependencies:
...
  font_awesome: any
...
```

Then in your code you can use

```
FontAwesome.icon
```

For Material Icons you can just use the codepoints Like below. Note the newer icons does not have an official list for the codepoints.

```
 const Icon(IconData(0xe1c8, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')), // note the `0x` before the actual codepoint.
```

If you cant find the codepoint of the icon you need then you can also just download it from MaterialIcons and add it as an image (not sure if this is optimal)

I have also added a possible list ref, but don't think its what you want.

References

- [Font Awesome Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome)
- [Font Awesome Site](https://fontawesome.com/)
- [Material Icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=signal&icon=signal_cellular_3_bar&style=baseline)
- [Possible List for Code points](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/813#issuecomment-401601344)

Comment: It has just an icon like this 'FontAwesomeIcons.signal', that is not good enough. I want a series of signal icon, from low level signal icon to high level signal icon as our mobile antenna.

Answer (score 0):

you can add [GroovinMaterialIcons](https://pub.dev/packages/groovin_material_icons) to your project and get more Material Icons.

check https://pub.dev/packages/groovin_material_icons.